# How to convert month day and year column to a day of the week

Tags: r

I have 3 columns: month, day, and year. They are all in integer format. For example, in one row, year == 2013, month == 1, day == 1. I need to use these 3 columns to create a new column that says what day of the week it is (i.e. Tuesday). Thanks.

Comment: @Vlo Their date is all one column though and hyphenated. I have 3 columns in my table, each seperate with year, month, and day.

Comment: Paste the columns together with paste0()

Comment: @Vlo I figured it out with the lubridate package thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to derive date from 3 columns. Solution usages `base` libraries

```
# sample data to demonstrate conversion. Dates are random
df <- data.frame(year = c(2018, 2016, 2017, 2018),
                 month = c(7:10), 
                 day = c(9:12) )
df
#      year month day
#    1 2018     7   9
#    2 2016     8  10
#    3 2017     9  11
#    4 2018    10  12

# Convert and add additional column as date. Use of paste and sprintf.
df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$year, sprintf("%02d",df$month), sprintf("%02d", df$day) , sep = "-"), "%Y-%m-%d")
# Find and populate date-of-week
df$day_of_week <- weekdays(df$date)

#Result:
df
#      year month day       date day_of_week
#    1 2018     7   9 2018-07-09      Monday
#    2 2016     8  10 2016-08-10   Wednesday
#    3 2017     9  11 2017-09-11      Monday
#    4 2018    10  12 2018-10-12      Friday
```